# How to Upload Photo and return GPS co-ords

Tags: php, gps, geotagging

All,
I'm tinkering with a simp[le form to upload a photo, store it within my server & then return the GPS co-ordinates. 
I'm using the standard PHP file upload script and a GPs solution i found here. It allows me to upload files but does not return the GPS co-ordinates. Can anyone help identify the issue please?
My complete php is:

```html
    <?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
     if($check !== false) {
      echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
      $uploadOk = 1;
     } else {
      echo "File is not an image.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
     }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
     echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000000) {
     echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
     echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
     echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
     } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
    }

    read_gps_location($target_file);

    /**
     * Returns an array of latitude and longitude from the Image file
     * @param image $file
     * @return multitype:number |boolean
     */
    function read_gps_location(){
     if (is_file($target_file)) {
      $info = exif_read_data($target_file);
      if (isset($info['GPSLatitude']) && isset($info['GPSLongitude']) &&
       isset($info['GPSLatitudeRef']) && isset($info['GPSLongitudeRef']) &&
       in_array($info['GPSLatitudeRef'], array('E','W','N','S')) && in_array($info['GPSLongitudeRef'], array('E','W','N','S'))) {

       $GPSLatitudeRef  = strtolower(trim($info['GPSLatitudeRef']));
       $GPSLongitudeRef = strtolower(trim($info['GPSLongitudeRef']));

       $lat_degrees_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][0]);
       $lat_minutes_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][1]);
       $lat_seconds_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][2]);
       $lng_degrees_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][0]);
       $lng_minutes_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][1]);
       $lng_seconds_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][2]);

       $lat_degrees = $lat_degrees_a[0] / $lat_degrees_a[1];
       $lat_minutes = $lat_minutes_a[0] / $lat_minutes_a[1];
       $lat_seconds = $lat_seconds_a[0] / $lat_seconds_a[1];
       $lng_degrees = $lng_degrees_a[0] / $lng_degrees_a[1];
       $lng_minutes = $lng_minutes_a[0] / $lng_minutes_a[1];
       $lng_seconds = $lng_seconds_a[0] / $lng_seconds_a[1];

       $lat = (float) $lat_degrees+((($lat_minutes*60)+($lat_seconds))/3600);
       $lng = (float) $lng_degrees+((($lng_minutes*60)+($lng_seconds))/3600);

       //If the latitude is South, make it negative. 
       //If the longitude is west, make it negative
       $GPSLatitudeRef  == 's' ? $lat *= -1 : '';
       $GPSLongitudeRef == 'w' ? $lng *= -1 : '';

       return array(
        'lat' => $lat,
        'lng' => $lng
       );
      }           
     }
     return false;
    } 


    ?>
```

Comment: No errors are shown just returns the statements of file upload and file type. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoke function read_gps_location($target_file); but you don't print the output

try changing this line

```
read_gps_location($target_file);
```

to

```
print_r(read_gps_location($target_file));
```

To see the output. It should be either array or false.

Comment: That breaks the upload process completely so i get no returned results at all and the file doesnt upload.